# zend framework - is it possible to make a 'redirect' script in the library

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

Is it possible? How?

Let's say I have the ff:

```
class My_Redirect
{
  function test()
  {
     // some testing
     // another testing
     // redirect script
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, speaking technically. But since the 'controller' part of a MVC application does the request/response handling, I would not recommend it. The library can be seen as part of your 'models'.

If you want to redirect, you can use the controller helper `redirector`, you can use the `Zend_Controller_Response` object, or you can use the plain old php `header()` function (not recommended).